# Ember.js Routing only wildcard /#/path but not /#path

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I've come up against a problem which can't possibly be unique to me, and looks like it'd be an issue with any SPA framework (or any framework which utilizes /#/ or /# conventions in its routing...

I'm trying to handle 404 in my Ember app.  Currently i'm using the format of `this.route('error', {path: "*path"});` at the bottom of my router map, however i've found an issue that if I have links within my pages to divs within the same page.

Ordinarily, I would use `<a href='#link-to-some-div'>Link</a>`, however I now can't do this, because the link is caught by the catch-all route map.

I can get around this by linking using a class, or writing some js, something along the lines of

```
$(".next-panel").click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+$(this).data('link')).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});


<div id='panel-1'>
    <button class='next-panel' data-link='panel-2'>Click</button>
</div>
<div id='panel-2'>
</div>
```

but I think this will be a more generic problem in the long run.

**Is there a way of differentiating between /#/ and /# in a router?**

Comment: Have you already tried `this.route('missing', { path: "/*path" });`?

Comment: I have, it doesn't seem to make a difference.  The solution may in fact be to use the javascript I posted above.

Comment: Alternative you could use Hashbang URLs for your routes, e.g. `/!yourRoute`. I blogged about how to implement it: http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/09/03/javascript-mvc-ember-js-and-seo-crawl-with-hashbang-location/ .

Comment: Interesting article, thanks :)  I don't need to worry about SEO for my app, but given the annoyance of the concept of hashes in URLs in general (this is only 1 use case, but i'm sure it's going to crop up again), I will be looking at it further.

Comment: Yeah it is just another workaround to separate anchor hashes from the routes :-). And you could just copy paste it :-). Alternatively you could maybe use the history location?

Comment: Concerned about the lack of browser support with HTML5 History, otherwise it would be the best solution for this app.